# Is it Possible to Crawl Dark Web pages ?

Tags: web-crawler, analytics, bigdata

So far, I am crawling data from different sources as live streaming Twitter and Facebook API and store it in separate DB. After that, I am using this big data in order to understand users behavior and some other kinds of analysis.

What I am trying to do is the same but at Dark Web Pages, I want to crawl all web pages that can be accessed by TOR explorer. I searched in several blogs about such a thing, but what I found is all of them are crawling only log files.

Is it possible to crawl dark web pages as we do with social media platforms API's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible - we've been doing it for years. We use Ubuntu so we install tor on our crawlers:

`apt get install tor`

and our python script run `urllib` requests for .onion links against the service via port  9050.

if you don't feel like developing your own crawler you're welcome to try ours at [https://webhose.io](https://webhose.io/dark-web-data)

Comment: Is there any guide blog or tutorial you can recommend, that shows how to create our own web crawler ? Thanks in advance.